# Eclipse Plug-in:How can I add a new entry ( say after right click->New->Dynamic Web Project) or for that matter any other existing group?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using menuContribution in my plugin.xml currently, I know of two ways to add entries into a context menu.

1. `<menuContribution
               locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=additions">`
2. `<menuContribution
               locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=new">`

But they don't let you add after a specific group as such.

Any inputs will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Abbas

Answer (score 1):

Soe of these menus are special and you normally don't use the `menus` extension point for these.

The following comes to mind - but there are likely more:

- "File" -> "New..." - use the `newWizard` extension point
- The "New" toolbar bottom - same
- Navigator context menu "New..." - same
- "File" -> "Import..." - use the `importWizard` extension point
- "File" -> "Export..." - use the `exportWizard` extension point
- "Search" menu - use the `searchPages` extension point
- "Window" -> "Open Perspective" - use the `perspectives` extension point
- "Window" -> "Show View" - use the `perspectives` extension point
- Most of the sub-menus of the "Run" menu
- ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use ID of any contribution item (which is present in the menu you are contributing to) in place of `additions` or `new`. `additions` is just the id of an invisible separator.

Comment: Thanks,I tried getting the id of the contribution item after which I need to insert a new entry, it just returns "menu:common.new.menu?after=new" using the PluginSpy in eclipse... any idea how do we get the Id or maybe an example would help

Comment: Perhaps look in whatever plugin "Dynamic Web Project" is defined? Also note that the "New" menu is a bit special: it gets contributions from `<newWizards>` extension point, and if "Dynamic Web Project" is contributed in this way I think what you want is impossible.

Comment: See here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/dialogs_wizards_newWizards.htm